# Inline styling vs !imporant styling

Tags: css

Which of the following is more appropriate:

```
<div class="someClass">

.someClass{
    color: blue !important;
}


or 

<div style="color:blue;">
```

These are, in my book, both wrong, but if I have to choose between one or the other, which should i choose?

Here is an example fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jfakey/zaot4c1y/1/

In it, you can see several different examples of how they are working.

Comment: Both are different things.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Do they both do different things here?

Comment: Technically, neither is "wrong", so this question is asking for opinions.

Comment: Both should be avoid using, only in extreme cases

Comment: Use the one that works best for you ... `!important` has the benefit of keeping the markup clean, which is the way I do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two entirely different concepts.

**The Importance of `!important`**

The `!important` will force any styles that use it to be applied to the affected elements and will give them priority over any existing declarations, including inline ones :

```
<!-- This element will actually appear blue due to your !important style -->
<div class="someClass" style='color:red'>or</div>
```

[Precedence and Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) plays a vital role in CSS in determining which styles are / aren't applied to elements. The `!important` declaration is essentially a mechanism to circumvent these rules in some scenarios where the developer deems necessary.

**Regarding Inline Styles**

Inline styles will generally be given a high-level of priority and should be applied, unless in scenarios where `!important` is used. Additionally, inline styles may often be fine for single styles, but if you find yourself using the same style multiple times :

```
<div style='font-weight: bold; text-align: center; color: purple'>...</div>
<div style='font-weight: bold; text-align: center; color: purple'>...</div>
<div style='font-weight: bold; text-align: center; color: purple'>...</div>
```

Then you may be better off simply defining a style that all of these elements can use :

```
.purple-centered-bold {
     font-weight: bold; text-align: center; color: purple;
}
```

along with :

```
<div class='purple-centered-bold'>...</div>
<div class='purple-centered-bold'>...</div>
<div class='purple-centered-bold'>...</div>
```

This not only allows you your markup to appear significantly cleaner, but it also makes your code more maintainable (i.e. any changes can be made within a single CSS style and applied to all elements that use it).

**Example**

[image]

```css
.someClass{
    color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="someClass" style='color:red'>class="someClass",style="color:red"</div>
<div style='color:red'>style="color:red"</div>
<div style="color:blue;">style="color:blue"</div>
```

Comment: Worth noting might be that even an inline style can have `!important`, and as such, override an external CSS rule having `!important`

Answer (score 2):

Minor inline styling isn't a big deal, but if your html starts looking like this:

```
<div style="color:blue; font-weight: bold; background-color: white; font-family: cursive">
```

then you should put the styling in CSS. `!important` will make that styling property override anything else that tries to style it, such as bootstrap css. `!important` is just to make sure your custom styling doesn't get messed up if you install some package that tries to style your content by default.

Answer (score 0):

If there is lots of HTML , using Class is better option. So you can avoid writing inline style in several places. If its using only for that particular case inline with div is the best way.